# Does beginning a transaction with a serializable isolation level block immediately?

Tags: xamarin.android, ado.net, sqlite-net

Should any reads (`SELECT`) made to `Table1` by another thread, after the transaction is started but before the `UPDATE` is executed, be blocked, or does the `UPDATE` need to first begin execution?

```
var _con = new SqliteConnection( "Data Source=" + FileName );
_con.Open();

SqliteCommand _cmd = _con.CreateCommand();
_cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

_con.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable);

// UPDATE
_cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Table1 SET field1 = 'a' WHERE Id = 1";
_cmd.ExecuteReader();

_cmd.Transaction.Commit();
```

Comment: I suppose it would be rather inefficient for a single transaction to read-lock the entire database.

Comment: SQLite does not have different isolation levels; all transactions are serializable. And the behaviour depends on whether you are using WAL mode. And this has nothing to do with Microsoft's SQL Server.

Comment: @CL. To be clear, are all SQLite statements implicitly executed as, or "wrapped in", a transaction, and are these implicit transactions serialziable by default as well? Doe's WAL allow for dirty reads - *"WAL provides more concurrency as readers do not block writers and a writer does not block readers. Reading and writing can proceed concurrently."* - that doesn't sound like a serializable isolation level to me?

Comment: *"The original content is preserved in the database file and the changes are appended into a separate WAL file. [This] allows readers to continue operating from the original unaltered database while changes are simultaneously being committed into the WAL."*

Comment: So WAL is equivalent to the Read Uncommitted ISO isolation level?

Comment: No, WAL mode reads the committed data from earlier transactions; the uncommitted data is only in the WAL and is ignored by other transactions.

Comment: @CL. Sorry, I meant Read Committed, which allows for non-repeatable and phantom reads?

Comment: No, only data from transactions committed before the current one started is readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQLite, all transactions (explicit and automatics ones) are serializable.

By default, SQLite's transactions [are DEFERRED](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html), which means that read/write locks are taken only when the database file actually needs to be read/written (and writes usually happen only when the caches is flushed when the transaction commits).

In journal rollback mode, readers and a writer block each other; in WAL mode, readers and a writer can access the DB concurrently, but there can still be only one writer.

However, Xamarin does not use the defaults; [BeginTransaction()](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Database.Sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.BeginTransaction/) immediately starts a transaction in EXCLUSIVE mode, which means that it conflicts with all other concurrent transactions. (WAL mode makes no difference.)
Apparently, you are not supposed to use any concurrency in Xamarin.

Comment: The note about xamarin explains a lot, and why I've been getting away with a few mishaps (didn't think I had that much luck). Better safe than sorry I guess. Because I cannot step-debug through a "background" service that is running within it's own process (vs debugger wont attach; times out), printouts are the only way to test/debug sqlite code within it (I guess maybe gdb could possibly be used on the device itself, but I never setup up symbols for .net clr, and am not sure if it's even possible, and it's been a long time since I've even used gdb).